# How to Generate 32 bit integers random number using marsenne twister Algorithm

Tags: c#, python, random, mt19937

How to Generate 32 bit integers random number using marsenne twister Algorithm? And save it to binary file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: help me for python or C# @PeterO.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // Create the random number engine
    std::mt19937::result_type seed = std::random_device()();
    auto engine = std::mt19937(seed);
    auto random = [&engine]() { return engine(); };

    // Generate some random numbers
    auto constexpr n = 1000;
    auto numbers = std::vector<std::mt19937::result_type>();
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(numbers), n, random);

    // Write them out to a file
    auto fout = std::ofstream("random_numbers.bin", std::ios::binary);
    fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(numbers.data()), 
        n * sizeof(decltype(numbers)::value_type));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i cant understand pseudu code, kindly give me real code @user515430

Comment: It is C++, not pseudo code. The steps (but not the syntax) will be the same in any language.

Comment: this is code that i've tried [MT199937 CODE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q-BPXiTSjwlp1srC4SSz74B8pGqaKTWR)

i don't know how get 32 bits random integer and send output to binary file